# Probability of selecting $j$-th ball from urn is $\mathbb{P}(B_j\mid A_k)=\frac{k}{n}$

Tags: probability, combinatorics, conditional-probability

> An urn contains $M$ balls, of which $M_1$ are white. A set of $n$ balls is obtained either
>   by sampling balls with replacement (each ball is replaced in the urn after it is drawn), or
>   without replacement (a ball once drawn remains out of the urn).
>
> Let $B_j$ be the event that
>   the ball selected at the $j$-th step is white, and $A_k$ the event that a sample of size $n$ contains
>   exactly $k$ white balls. Show that $$\mathbb{P}(B_j\mid A_k)=\frac{k}{n}$$both for sampling with replacement and for sampling without replacement.

It seems clear that $\mathbb{P}(B_1) =\frac{M_1}{M}$ and $\mathbb{P}(B_2) = \frac{M_1}{M} \frac{M-M1}{M-1} + \frac{M_1}{M} \frac{M_1-1}{M-1} = \frac{M_1}{M}$. We can probably suspect that $\mathbb{P}(B_j)=\frac{M_1}{M}$ as well, if $j \leq M_1$.

However, it's not clear for me how to construct the probability $\mathbb{P}(B_j\mid A_k$) from here.

If I'm not wrong, $$\mathbb{P}(A_k) = \frac{\left( \begin{array}{c} M_1\\k \end{array} \right)\left( \begin{array}{c} M - M_1\\ n -k \end{array} \right)}{\left( \begin{array}{c} M\\n \end{array} \right)} \tag{1}$$due to hypergeometric distribution. From here $$\mathbb{P}(B_j\mid A_k)=\frac{\mathbb{P}(B_j \cap A_k)}{\mathbb{P}(A_k)} $$.

But I'm not sure how to estimate the $\mathbb{P}(B_j \cap A_k)$. As far as I understand, instead of all possible events as in (1), event $\{ B_j \cap A_k \}$ should cover a part of it where the $B_j$ holds, but not sure how to get to the $\frac{k}{n}$ from here.

Any hints or suggestions would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To compute $P(B_j\cap A_k)$, you have to get your hands dirty with some combinatorics. Suppose that our sample space consists of all ordered selections of $n$ balls without replacement. There are $\frac{M!}{(M-n)!}$ such selections. We must count the number of sequences where there are $k$ white balls *and* where the $j^{th}$ ball is white.

There are $M_1$ ways to choose the white ball that goes in the $j^{th}$ spot, then $\binom{M_1-1}{k-1}$ ways to choose the other $k-1$ balls, then $\binom{M-M_1}{n-k}$ ways to choose the black balls. Then, the $n-1$ balls (excepting the ball in spot $j$) can be ordered in $(n-1)!$ ways. Therefore, 
$$
P(B_j\cap A_k)=\frac{M_1 \binom{M_1-1}{k-1}\binom{M-M_1}{n-k}(n-1)!}{\frac{M!}{(M-n)!}}
$$

You need to redo all this work in the situation where you sample with replacement.

---

Alternatively, you could argue that given $A_k$, all $\binom{n}k$ ways of choosing the order of black and white balls are equally likely, and there are $\binom{n-1}{k-1}$ of those which have a white ball in their $j^{th}$ spot, so $P(B_j|A_k)=\binom{n-1}{k-1}/\binom{n}k=k/n$.

Comment: Thanks, very clear explanation!